# Android AVD does not have a browser

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Hi can u plzz tell me what are the packages needed to have a browser in my Android Virtual Device??

I did a manual install of the Android SDK and downloaded and installed the following packages: 
1.For API 14 I have the SDK Platform,SYSTEM Image and SDK Platform tools.

2. I also downloaded and installed the SDK platforms of API 7,8,10,12.

**Then I created a virtual device using the system Image of API 14 but it does not have a browser??**

Comment: AFAIK, that should not be possible. There should be a Browser icon in your home screen's launcher.

Answer (score 0):

All AVDs come with a browser standard (it is the globe icon), named Browser (if you look for it in the app drawer).  You don't need even need the Google APIs.

It doesn't matter which API you use - they all have a browser native, and you don't need to do anything special.